# Adding a decimal place to file size

Tags: java, filesize, fileutils

I have some code that is going to my local Downloads folder and getting the file size of a file, and I've converted it to human readable format using byteCountToDisplaySize(), but I need it to return 1 additional decimal point. 
The code below returns 13 MB, but I need it to return 13.8 MB.
How can I do this?

```
public void seeTheSizeOfTheFile(String fileName String expectedFileSize) {
      String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + fileName;
      File file = new File(filePath);
      long actualFileSize = FileUtils.sizeOf(file);
      String readableFileSize = FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(actualFileSize);
}
```

Comment: The way byteCountToDisplaySize is built, it always rounds to the nearest GB, MB, or KB. So there is no way to get the decimal using this method. See: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils/byteCountToDisplaySize

Comment: If you want to add a decimal place, you could use [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) method in File class. This returns the length of the file in bytes. Then you can use this value and round it to one decimal place in a different unit.